# Сгенерировать изображения заданного размера

Tags: php, изображения, gd

Хочу сделать простенький генератор товаров для интернет-магазина.
Нужно сгенерировать картинки-заглушки для каждого товара. 
Что-то типа этого:
[image: gravatar]

Нужен скрипт или подсказка как это сделать.

Если есть какой-то бесплатный ресурс, который отдает разные изображения через api, то тоже пойдет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С [robohash.org](http://robohash.org/) можно получать **шикарные разноцветные глазасто-ушастые тостеры**.

Ссылка такого вида:

```
https://robohash.org/какая-то_строчка?set=set3
```

[image: stackoverflow.png][image: ru.stackoverflow.png]

(сгенерированы по строчкам `stackoverflow.png` и `ru.stackoverflow.png`)

Алгоритм **детерминированный**, по одной и той же строчке будет выдаваться одна и та же картинка.

Чтобы не слишком плющить этот сервис, можете поднять его у себя [из исходников (Python!)](https://github.com/e1ven/Robohash), можно даже на собственном наборе составляющих, более подходящих под ваши цели. Или хотя бы кэшировать ответы на собственном сервере.

Answer (score 4):

С помощью ru.gravatar.com можете получать картинки нужного размера.
Пример на php:

```
$email = "someone@somewhere.com";
$default = "http://www.somewhere.com/homestar.jpg";
$size = 40;

$grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) ) . "?d=" . urlencode( $default ) . "&s=" . $size;

echo "<img src=" . $grav_url . " alt='' />"
```

Другие примеры:
https://ru.gravatar.com/site/implement/

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример для http://ru.gravatar.com/

```
<? 
    /**
     * Get either a Gravatar URL or complete image tag for a specif ied email address.
     *
     * @param string $email The email address
     * @param string $s Size in pixels, defaults to 80px [ 1 - 2048 ]
     * @param string $d Default imageset to use [ 404 | mm | identicon | monsterid | wavatar ]
     * @param string $r Maximum rating (inclusive) [ g | pg | r | x ]
     * @param boole $img True to return a complete IMG tag False for just the URL
     * @param array $atts Optional, additional key/value attributes to include in the IMG tag
     * @return String containing either just a URL or a complete image tag
     * @source http://gravatar.com/site/implement/images/php/
     */
    function get_gravatar( $email, $s = 80, $d = 'mm', $r = 'g', $img = false, $atts = array() ) {
        $url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/';
        $url .= md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) );
        $url .= "?s=$s&d=$d&r=$r";
        if  ( $img ) {
            $url = '<img src="' . $url . '"';
            foreach ( $atts as $key => $val )
                    $url .= ' ' . $key . '="' . $val . '"';
            $url .= ' />';
        }
        return $url;
    }

    echo '<img src="' . get_gravatar('custom123123', 100, 'identicon')  . '" alt="">';
    ?>
```

Для каждого email'a будет генерироваться случайная картинка. Чтобы достигнуть желаемого результата в качестве email'a можно передавать какой-то рандомный набор символов, который с нулевой долей вероятности будет реально существующем email'ом.

Comment: Я так понял, что там я должен зарегаться и за мной будет закреплена определенная картинка. А мне нужно, например, сгенерировать 200 разных.

Comment: Там есть API, который позволяет получать аватар привязанный к email'у. При отсутствии email'a буде возвращаться стандартная картинка, в том числе можно указать чтобы возвращалась картинка в том виде в котором тебе нужно.